# I am getting error like ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>, when running ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-template

When i am trying to run this code in ansible, i am getting error like

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'
The error appears to be in '/home/c22377/icoms1.yml': line 15, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
  handlers:
    - name: starting one time job
      ^ here
```

I need to use handlers, can you correct me?

```
---
- hosts: catl
  name: "checking file ran or not"
  tasks:
    - shell: tail -1 test/test.log|awk '{print $8,$9,$10}'
      register: result
    - shell: date | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
      name: checking todays date
      register: time
    - debug:
             msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      when: result.stdout == time.stdout
      notify: starting one time job
  handlers:
    - name: starting one time job
      tasks:
        - shell: date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from:

```
handlers:
- name: starting one time job
  tasks:
  - shell: date
```

to:

```
handlers:
- name: starting one time job
  shell: date
```

Comment: Right, since [Handlers: (which) running operations on change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html) are not the same as [Tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/basic_concepts.html#tasks). See also [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html)